# Android App to communicate to Rpi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi2

I am making IOT project in which I need to send a stop command from android app to Raspberry pi to stop the Raspberry Pi activity at the moment as I am not able to find the thing for which I am looking for.

Comment: Sounds generic; can you please elaborate further?

Comment: The project is smart plug in which excess power usage of a device or usage of power when device is not used get automatically get switched off.Now I want to make an android app to communicate like send stop command to raspberry pi to stop it.Furhter work to stop the device is been done in Rpi.I just need the thing between android and Rpi.